# Android development through Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I try to use the android development tools trough Eclipse Luna.

Exactly I try to use the JBoss for [cordova developmet](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article3.php)

I have a problem to run the Android emulator. So I tried first to create a clear Android Application project and it have the following error.

[image]

[image]
What should I do to fix them and run the emulator properly?

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: You have an issue in `styles.xml` that is causing ANT to fail to build your `R` file, causing errors in `MainActivity`. Please post the contents of `styles.xml`. Check the console (not error log) for more info.

Comment: I think the project is missing the android support library.

Right Click on Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

Comment: @MattClark here is the file http://www.filedropper.com/styles_2

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed I tried it but it gives me [2015-02-11 09:32:57 - SDK Manager]   URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r21.0.3.zip (Access denied)
[2015-02-11 09:32:57 - SDK Manager] Done. Nothing was installed.

Comment: I have installed all libraries of SDK Android which I could find from my programs but when I open the SDK Manager from Eclipse it seems that they are Unistalled.

Comment: Try running Eclipse as Administrator

Comment: @foc, Running eclipse as admin will not help, it will change your paths, and make android fail to launch, so don't do that, unnecessary. Also, please click the edit button above and paste the contents of your `styles.xml`. I, and 99% of the community will not download external files.

Comment: Having this file throw errors with just the default data means that you should try `Chris`' method below, it seems as if you are missing `appcompat_v7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBar is found in support library v7. Maybe it's missing.
You can right click in your project -> Properties -> Android 
There you should see a library added with a green mark like the following:
[image]

If you don't have any library there, you should import the library by going to: File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace 
Then look for your library v7 into the sdk folder like the following picture:

[image]

Then click finish:

[image]

And go back to right click on your project and go to properties to add the library by clicking in the Add... button and selecting the library:

[image]

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It seems to run as solutin but maybe the problem with the eclipse is more general to me because it gives me this [2015-02-11 10:04:09 - android-support-v7-appcompat] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-02-11 10:04:24 - android-support-v7-appcompat] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\jarlist.cache